# DrayTek SSL VPN can't see SIP Server

Tags: vpn

I have set up an SSL VPN using 2 Draytek 2860 routers. Connection is fine and I can see and ping all connected IPs

Except 1 IP, My SIP server IP. I can ping it locally, but not remotely via SSL VPN.

I can login to remote router also once connected. Am I missing something or should I be able to see it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue

i had "From first subnet to remote network, you have to do"

Set to Route, Changed to NAT all good now :)